# How is there internal fragmentation in paging and no external fragmentation?

Tags: memory, memory-management, operating-system

Please explain it nicely. Don't just write definition. Also explain what it does and how is it different from segmentation.

Answer (score 14):

Fragmentation needs to be considered with memory allocation techniques. Paging is basically not a memory allocation technique, but rather a means of providing virtual address spaces.

Considering the comparison with segmentation, what you're probably asking about is the difference between a memory allocation technique using fixed size blocks (like the pages of paging, assuming 4KB page size here) and a technique using variable size blocks (like the segments used for segmentation).

Now, assume that you directly use the page allocation interface to implement memory management, that is you have two functions for dealing with memory:

- `alloc_page`, which allocates a single page and returns a pointer to the beginning of the newly available address space, and
- `free_page`, which frees a single, allocated page.

Now suppose all of your currently available virtual memory is used, but you need to store 1 additional byte. You call `alloc_page` and get a 4KB block of memory. You only use 1 byte of that huge block, but also the other 4095 bytes are, from the perspective of the allocator, used. If this happens multiple times eventually all pages will be allocated, so further calls to `alloc_page` will fail. Even if you just need another additional byte (which could be one of the 4095 that got wasted above) the allocator will tell you that you're out of memory. This is internal fragmentation.

If, on the other hand, you would use variable sized blocks (like in segmentation), then you're vulnerable to external fragmentation: Suppose you manage 6 bytes of memory (`F` means "free"):

```
FFFFFF
```

You first allocate 3 bytes for `a`, then 1 for `b` and finally 2 bytes for `c`:

```
aaabcc
```

Now you free both `a` and `c`, leaving only `b` allocated:

```
FFFbFF
```

You now have 5 bytes of unused memory, but if you try to allocate a block of 4 bytes (which is less than the available memory) the allocation will fail due to the unfavorable placement of the memory for `b`. This is external fragmentation.

Now, if you extend your page allocator to be able to allocate multiple pages and add `alloc_multiple_pages`, you have to deal with both internal **and** external fragmentation.

Answer (score 6):

There is no external fragmentation in paging but internal fragmentation exists.
First, we need to understand what is external fragmentation. External fragmentation occurs when we have a memory to accommodate a process but it's not continuous.
How does it not occur in paging?
Paging divides virtual memory or all processes into equal-sized pages and physical memory into fixed size frames. So you are typically fixing equal size blocks called pages into equal block shaped spaces called frames! Try to visualize and conclude that there can never be external fragmentation.

In the case of segmentation, we divide virtual addresses into different sized blocks that is why there may be the case some blocks in main memory must stick together or compact to make space for the new process! I hope it helps!

Answer (score 3):

When a process is divided into fix sized pages, there is generally some leftover space in the last page(internal fragmentation). When there are many processes, each of their last page's unused area could add up to be greater than or equal to size of one page. Now even if you have to total free size of one page or more but you cannot load a new page because a page has to be continuous. External fragmentation has happened. So, I don't think external fragmentation is completely zero in paging.

EDIT: It is all about how External Fragmentation is defined. The collection of internal fragmentation do not contribute to external fragmentation. **External fragmentation is contributed by the empty space which is EXTERNAL to partition(or page)**. So if suppose there are only two frames in main memory ,say of size 16B, each occupied by only 1B data. The internal fragmentation in each frame is 15B. The total unused space is 30B. Now if you want to load one new page of some process, you will see that you do not have any frame available. You are unable to load a new page eventhough you have 30B unused space. Will you call this as external fragmentation? Answer is no. Because these 15B unused space are INTERNAL to the pages. So in paging, internal fragmentation is possible but not external fragmentation.

Comment: Thanks Ayush for the answer. I'm from BIET Jhansi :)

Answer (score 1):

Paging allows a process to be allocated physical memory in non-contiguous fashion. I will answer that why external fragmentation can't occur in paging.

External frag occurs when a process, which was allocated contiguous memory , is unloaded from physical memory, which creates a hole (free space ) in the memory.

Now if a new process comes, which requires more memory than this hole, then we won't be able to allocate *contiguous memory* to that process due to *non contiguous* nature of free memory, this is called external fragmentation.

Now, the problem above originated due to the constraint of allocating contiguous memory to the process. This is what paging solved by allowing process to get *non contiguous* physical memory.

Answer (score 0):

In paging, the probability of having external fragmentation is very low although internal fragmentation may occur.

In paging scheme, the whole main memory and the virtual memory is divided into some fixed size slots which are called pages (in case of virtual memory) and page frames (in case of main memory or RAM or physical memory). So, whenever a process is executed in main memory, it occupies the entire space of a page frame. Let us say, the main memory has 4096 page frames with each page frame having a size of 4096 bytes. Suppose, there is a process P1 which requires 3000 bytes of space for its execution in main memory. So, in order to execute P1, it is brought from virtual memory to main memory and placed in a page frame (F1) but P1 requires only 3000 bytes of space for its execution and as a result of which (4096 - 3000 = 1096 bytes) of space in the page frame F1 is wasted. In other words, this denotes the case of internal fragmentation in the page frame F1.

Again, external fragmentation may occur if some space of the main memory could not be included in a page frame. But this case is very rare as usually the size of a main memory, the size of a page frame as well as the total no. of page frames in main memory can be expressed in terms of power of 2.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I've understood, I would answer your question like so:

**Why is there internal fragmentation with paging?**

Because a page has fixed size, but processes may request more or less space. Say a page is 32 units, and a process requests 20 units. Then when a page is given to the requesting process, that page is no longer useable despite having 12 units of free "internal" space.

**Why is there *no* external fragmentation with paging?**

Because in paging, a process is *allowed* to be allocated spaces that are non-contiguous in the physical memory. Meanwhile, the logical representation of those blocks will be contiguous in the virtual memory. This is what I mean:

A process requires 128 units of space. This is 4 pages as in the previous example. Unregardless of the actual page numbers (formally frame numbers) in the physical memory, you give those pages the numbers 0, 1, 2, and 3. This is the virtual representation that is the defining characteristic of paging itself. Those pages may be 21, 213, 23, 234 in the actual physical memory. But they can really be anything, contiguous or non-contiguous. Therefore, even if paging leaves small *free* spaces in between *used* spaces, those small free spaces can still be used together as if they were one contiguous block of space. That's why external fragmentation won't happen.

Answer (score 0):

Frames are allocated as units. If the memory requirements of a process do not happen to coincide with page boundaries, the last frame allocated may not be completely full.

For example, if the page size is 2,048 bytes, a process of 72,766 bytes will need 35 pages plus 1,086 bytes. It will be allocated 36 frames, resulting in internal fragmentation of 2,048 - 1,086 = 962 bytes. In the worst case, a process would need 11 pages plus 1 byte. It would be allocated 11 + 1 frames, resulting in internal fragmentation of almost an entire frame.

Comment: This answer doesn't address the problem completely. Not talking about external fragmentation at all.